# Magento2 Knockout js - translate variable text

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, localisation, translate

I'm trying to translate text that comes from a variable in Knockout html file, but I can;t find the right way. Here's some things I tried:

```
<dt class="label" data-bind="html: i18n(option.label)"></dt>
<dt class="label" data-bind="i18n: option.label"></dt>
<dt class="label"><!-- ko i18n: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
```

`option.label` returns a string like 'width' or 'height'. There words are included in a .csv translation file.

Answer (score 4):

both the following answer you give are good:

```
<dt class="label" data-bind="i18n: option.label"></dt>
<dt class="label"><!-- ko i18n: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
```

The `i18n` attribute in Magento javascript need a string. So the important point to verify is that the value given by `option.label` is a string and that string is in your `*.csv`.

It's like doing:

```
<dt class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'My label'"></dt>
<dt class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'My label' --><!-- /ko --></dt>
```

More details in the Magento Dev documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html#add_strings_ui_html

But sometime, you need to check if your translation is well generated in your pub/static folder.

Comment: I applied your suggestion and it seemed to be updated when making the change directly in the vendor folder, however, not if I apply it to a theme override. Further, it seems not to be translated. Do you have more information on how to provide translations outside the i18n CSV?